# Will Ubuntu on Local disk D be affected when I reinstall Windows 7 on Local Disk C

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I have Windows 7(Primary OS) and Ubuntu on my laptop. I have a problem with my wireless so I intend to reinstall Windows on "Local disk C".

If I reinstall Windows, will it affect my Ubuntu OS  installed on "Local disk D"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinstalling Windows on a separate drive will affect the Ubuntu installation in only one way *if the installation is done correctly*:

Windows will reinstall its own boot loader over Ubuntu's Grub boot loader. This will usually cause the machine to boot directly to Windows, not even giving you the chance to select Ubuntu.

This issue can be fixed here: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

To ensure the installation is safe, and it doesn't erase Ubuntu, make sure Windows never *touches* the D: drive (if that is where Ubuntu is installed). Only select the C: drive install, and triple check to make sure the D: drive isn't formatted as a Data or Backup drive.

<sub><sup>Only now do I realize that "D:" and "C:" drive icon text make faces representing which drives are okay for Windows to modify.</sup></sub>

Comment: Haahahahahaha +1 for noticing the faces :P